# nodejs межпроцессная коммуникация с помощью библиотеки node-ipc

Tags: node.js

Нужно организовать межпроцессное взаимодействие в NodeJS.
Выбрал библиотеку node-ipc (1 млн скачиваний)
Все отлично, примеры работают.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc

У меня остался единственный непонятный момент.
Клиент соединяется с сервером с помощью ipc.connectTo.
Дальше необходимо отправить сообщение серверу.
Для этого клиент (в примерах) слушает событие connect и при его получении вызывает уже emit.
Пример:

https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc/blob/master/example/unixWindowsSocket/basic/hello-client.js

У меня такой вопрос.
Я не хочу закрывать соединение клиент/сервер (по unix socket) и время от времени клиент будет отправлять серверу сообщения.

По идее событие connect (особенно в рамках одной машины) клиент должен получить только один раз.

Надо ли проверять наличие события connect перед отправкой emit ?
Или если connect еще не было - то emit встанет в очередь ?

Comment: у меня такое ощущение, что когда нет коннекта ("нет пока" и "нет из-за дисконнекта") сообщения улетают в никуда https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc/blob/master/dao/client.js#L32

Comment: После сборки node-ipc появляется функция и видно что идет просто запись в soket: this.socket.write(message);

function emit(type, data) {
  this.log("dispatching event to ", this.id, this.path, " : ", type, ",", data);
  let message = new import_js_message.default();
  message.type = type;
  message.data = data;
  if (this.config.rawBuffer) {
    message = Buffer.from(type, this.config.encoding);
  } else {
    message = eventParser.format(message);
  }
  if (!this.config.sync) {
    this.socket.write(message);
    return;
  }
  this.queue.add(syncEmit.bind(this, message));
}

Comment: Я просто думал что кто то пользовался на практике (1 млн скачиваний еженедельно) и посоветует правильный путь :)